# Raspbian and PyQt5 ImportError: No module named ‘PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5

Long story short I've installed PyQt5 through apt-get on my pi. Everything seems to work fine except the QWebEngineView. For some reason I get this message:

ImportError: No module named ‘PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets’ when I try to import it.

PyQt5 version: 5.8.2

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you in advance for your time.

`apt-cache search pyqt5` returns

```
pyqt5-dev - Development files for PyQt5
pyqt5-dev-tools - Development tools for PyQt5
pyqt5-doc - Documentation for PyQt5
pyqt5-examples - Examples and demos for PyQt5
pyqt5.qsci-dev - Development files for Python Qscintilla2 (Qt5)
python-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 - D-Bus Support for PyQt5 with Python
python-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5-dbg - D-Bus Support for PyQt5 (debug extensions for Python)
python-pyqt5 - Python bindings for Qt5
python-pyqt5-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5 (debug extensions)
python-pyqt5.enginio - Python 2 bindings for Enginio library
python-pyqt5.enginio-dbg - Python 2 bindings for Enginio library (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia - Python bindings for Qt5's Multimedia module
python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's Multimedia module (debug extensions)
python-pyqt5.qtopengl - Python bindings for Qt5's OpenGL module
python-pyqt5.qtopengl-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's OpenGL module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtpositioning - Python bindings for QtPositioning module
python-pyqt5.qtpositioning-dbg - Python bindings for QtPositioning module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtquick - Python bindings for QtQuick module
python-pyqt5.qtquick-dbg - Python bindings for QtQuick module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtsensors - Python bindings for QtSensors module
python-pyqt5.qtsensors-dbg - Python bindings for QtSensors module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtserialport - Python bindings for QtSerialPort module
python-pyqt5.qtserialport-dbg - Python bindings for QtSerialPort module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtsql - Python bindings for Qt5's SQL module
python-pyqt5.qtsql-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's SQL module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtsvg - Python bindings for Qt5's SVG module
python-pyqt5.qtsvg-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's SVG module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtwebkit - Python bindings for Qt5's WebKit module
python-pyqt5.qtwebkit-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's WebKit module (debug extensions)
python-pyqt5.qtwebsockets - Python bindings for Qt5's WebSockets module
python-pyqt5.qtwebsockets-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's WebSockets module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtx11extras - Python bindings for QtX11Extras module
python-pyqt5.qtx11extras-dbg - Python bindings for QtX11Extras module (debug extension)
python-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns - Python bindings for Qt5's XmlPatterns module
python-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns-dbg - Python bindings for Qt5's XmlPatterns module (debug extension)
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 - D-Bus Support for PyQt5 with Python 3
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5-dbg - D-Bus Support for PyQt5 (debug extensions for Python 3)
python3-pyqt5 - Python 3 bindings for Qt5
python3-pyqt5-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5 (debug extensions)
python3-pyqt5.enginio - Python 3 bindings for Enginio library
python3-pyqt5.enginio-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Enginio library (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qsci - Python 3 bindings for QScintilla 2 with Qt 5
python3-pyqt5.qsci-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QScintilla 2 (Qt 5 debug extensions)
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's Multimedia module
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's Multimedia module (debug extensions)
python3-pyqt5.qtopengl - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's OpenGL module
python3-pyqt5.qtopengl-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's OpenGL module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning - Python 3 bindings for QtPositioning module
python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QtPositioning module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtquick - Python 3 bindings for QtQuick module
python3-pyqt5.qtquick-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QtQuick module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtsensors - Python 3 bindings for QtSensors module
python3-pyqt5.qtsensors-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QtSensors module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtserialport - Python 3 bindings for QtSerialPort module
python3-pyqt5.qtserialport-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QtSerialPort module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtsql - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's SQL module
python3-pyqt5.qtsql-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's SQL module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtsvg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's SVG module
python3-pyqt5.qtsvg-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's SVG module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's WebKit module
python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's WebKit module (debug extensions)
python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's WebSockets module
python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's WebSockets module (debug extensions)
python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras - Python 3 bindings for QtX11Extras module
python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras-dbg - Python 3 bindings for QtX11Extras module (debug extension)
python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's XmlPatterns module
python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns-dbg - Python 3 bindings for Qt5's XmlPatterns module (debug extension)
pyqt5 - Build of PyQt5 compiled for eglfs Qt5 and Python3 on Raspbian
```

Comment: What is your version of PyQt5?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. It's 5.8.2.

Comment: You can run the following command: `apt-cache search pyqt5` and tell me what you get.

Comment: read this: https://marc.info/?l=kde-core-devel&m=142954900813235&w=2

Comment: I see nothing..

Comment: I've added it on the question.

Comment: So in a few words there's no way to get QWebEngineView in PyQt5...

Comment: If you look at the link a while ago you should see that debian does not support that module currently

Comment: That was clear. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** QtWebEngineWidgets is not normally available under Windows using versions of Python earlier than v3.5 because of compiler incompatibilities.

([Source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.html))

Comment: Windows is different to Raspbian(Linux)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is they forgot to compile the qtwebkit and -engine.
Or you download it and compile it yourself or you downgrade to a lower version. 
for Mac: pip3 install PyQt5==5.10 (this is a stable version).

Answer (score 0):

QtWebEngine needs to be installed separately.

```
python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

You can change this line to use apt-get when installing.

You may need to import your module and submodules depending on your code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

Are you installing custom PyQt5 build from a third party server to use priority codecs?

Answer (score -1):

QtWebEngine was based on the chromium, that's a big toolkit.

so not available/compatible for the all platform.

Maybe downgrade to QtWebKit-based was a more possible solution for you.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question